# Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'cart.itemsPrice'. This may cause incorrect behavior

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, redux

I have a order placement page and I cannot proceed to place the order because of this error. I don't see where exactly any of the state is being mutated, I think it's because the variables are dynamic but it still doesn't make sense to me.

Here's my page:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Link,
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useSearchParams,
} from "react-router-dom";
import {
  Form,
  Button,
  Row,
  Col,
  ListGroup,
  Image,
  Card,
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Loader from "../components/Loader";
import Message from "../components/Message";
import FormContainer from "../components/FormContainer";
import CheckoutSteps from "../components/CheckoutSteps";
import { createOrder } from "../actions/orderActions";
function PlaceOrderScreen() {
  const orderCreate = useSelector((state) => state.orderCreate);
  const { order, error, success } = orderCreate;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useNavigate();

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

  cart.itemsPrice = cart.cartItems
    .reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.price * item.qty, 0)
    .toFixed(2);
  cart.shippingPrice = (cart.itemsPrice > 100 ? 0 : 10).toFixed(2);
  cart.taxPrice = Number(0.082 * cart.itemsPrice).toFixed(2);

  cart.totalPrice = (
    Number(cart.itemsPrice) +
    Number(cart.shippingPrice) +
    Number(cart.taxPrice)
  ).toFixed(2);

  if (!cart.paymentMethod) {
    history("/payment");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (success) {
      history(`/order/${order._id}`);
      //   dispatch({ type: ORDER_CREATE_RESET });
    }
  }, [success, history]);

  const placeOrder = () => {
    dispatch(
      createOrder({
        orderItems: cart.cartItems,
        shippingAddress: cart.shippingAddress,
        paymentMethod: cart.paymentMethod,
        itemsPrice: cart.itemsPrice,
        shippingPrice: cart.shippingPrice,
        taxPrice: cart.taxPrice,
        totalPrice: cart.totalPrice,
      })
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <CheckoutSteps step1 step2 step3 step4 />
      <Row>
        <Col md={8}>
          {/* <Col md={4}> */}
          <ListGroup variant="flush">
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>Shipping</h2>
              <p>
                <strong>Shipping: </strong>
                {cart.shippingAddress.address}, {cart.shippingAddress.city}
                {"  "}
                {cart.shippingAddress.postalCode},{"  "}
                {cart.shippingAddress.country}
              </p>
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>Payment Method</h2>
              <p>
                <strong>Method: </strong>
                {cart.paymentMethod}
              </p>
            </ListGroup.Item>
            <ListGroup.Item>
              <h2>Order Items</h2>
              {cart.cartItems.length === 0 ? (
                <Message variant="info">Your cart is empty.</Message>
              ) : (
                <ListGroup variant="flush">
                  {cart.cartItems.map((item, index) => (
                    <ListGroup.Item key={index}>
                      <Row>
                        <Col md={1}>
                          <Image
                            src={item.image}
                            alt={item.name}
                            fluid
                            rounded
                          />
                        </Col>
                        <Col>
                          <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>
                            {item.name}
                          </Link>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={4}>
                          {item.qty} X ${item.price} = $
                          {(item.qty * item.price).toFixed(2)}
                        </Col>
                      </Row>
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                  ))}
                </ListGroup>
              )}
            </ListGroup.Item>
          </ListGroup>
          {/* </Col> */}
        </Col>
        <Col md={4}>
          <Card>
            <ListGroup variant="flush">
              <ListGroup.Item>
                <h2>Order Summary</h2>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Items:</Col>
                  <Col>${cart.itemsPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Shipping:</Col>
                  <Col>${cart.shippingPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Tax:</Col>
                  <Col>${cart.taxPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Row>
                  <Col>Total:</Col>
                  <Col>${cart.totalPrice}</Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                {error && <Message variant="danger">{error}</Message>}
              </ListGroup.Item>

              <ListGroup.Item>
                <Button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn-block"
                  disabled={cart.cartItems === 0}
                  onClick={placeOrder}
                >
                  Place Order
                </Button>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            </ListGroup>
          </Card>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PlaceOrderScreen;
```

My action:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import {
  ORDER_CREATE_REQUEST,
  ORDER_CREATE_SUCCESS,
  ORDER_CREATE_FAIL,
  ORDER_CREATE_RESET,
} from "../constants/orderConstants";

export const createOrder = (order) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_CREATE_REQUEST,
    });

    const {
      userLogin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.access}`,
      },
    };
    const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/orders/add/`, order, config);
    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_CREATE_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: ORDER_CREATE_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.detail
          ? error.response.data.detail
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

The error occurs on line 56. I thought it might have something to do with the itemsPrice variable, so I commented it out but it's all the variables that are bugging out.
I tried to run the createOrder function before the dispatch and dispatch it after that but I still had the same error. I read on [this](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-mutate-state) page about the error but I didn't understand anything.

I'm not sure why this is happening considering the fact that all the variables that I'm using are completely alright and visible on the page. The action isn't even being fired when supposed to because of this error.

EDIT:
This is my Order reducer:

```js
import {
  ORDER_CREATE_REQUEST,
  ORDER_CREATE_SUCCESS,
  ORDER_CREATE_FAIL,
  ORDER_CREATE_RESET,
} from "../constants/orderConstants";

export const orderCreateReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ORDER_CREATE_REQUEST:
      return {
        loading: true,
      };

    case ORDER_CREATE_SUCCESS:
      return {
        loading: false,
        success: true,
        order: action.payload,
      };

    case ORDER_CREATE_FAIL:
      return {
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload,
      };

    case ORDER_CREATE_RESET:
      return {};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: add the reducers to the question? that will be where your state mutation is as there where the state is touched :)

Comment: @Shaded There it is! :)

Comment: are you using redux-thunk by the way?

Comment: @Shaded Yes I am

Comment: can you share a git repo? that would make this a lot easier to debug

Comment: I will give it a go just gimme a minute

Comment: @Shaded https://github.com/StHeisenberg/ProjectRepo.git There it is!

Comment: https://github.com/StHeisenberg/ProjectRepo/pull/1 I open'd a pull request I think fixes your issue, read the comments as it explains it better :)

Comment: also you have some secrets in your `backend` folder, I'd make them environment variable and change them since you've pushed them to GitHub

Answer (score 0):

After some conversation in the comments we needed more context so created a git and opened a pull request with a potential solution.

See github Pull request:
https://github.com/StHeisenberg/ProjectRepo/pull/1

Comment: I've just tested your solution and the error still persists, it still says cart.itemsPrice even though now we don't directly mutate that variable. I don't see why

Comment: The way this is done, the tax price and the total price come out as NaN, which ends up in the post request throwing status 500, and if I bring out the variables outside of dispatch it ends up being an invariant error. I am really confused.

Comment: are you sure you pulled my branch? because cart.itemsPrice isn't in my code? Edit: it is its just been a good few hours, but still have you pulled my branch?

Comment: At this point I am just editing my code since I had some trouble with uploading the repo so I copied my original folder into a new one and that's how I uploaded the whole thing on GitHub. So basically I am just editing your changes into my original code by hand so I can, I just tried your last commit as well but tax and total now come out as 0 when it shouldn't. I don't understand why any of this happens right now. I tried getting rid of toFixed to just have everything as numbers and it still got me NaN.

Comment: I also tried parseInt and parseFloat, the values change to integers/floats but the tax and total price are still not changing for some reason

Comment: hmm well the problem that causes the original console error is because your trying to edit the redux state directly with cart so maybe look to refactor those cart edits to be included in a reducer for the cart, I'd really like to help more but without the backend I don't think I have to context to see the issues your seeing, in my edits I can see the events dispatching to the reducer where as with the original code they didn't and just threw a console error from you trying to edit the state directly

Comment: My backend is also included in the github repo. I am still trying to understand what's causing this problem and I still haven't managed to fix it